# using Actvator.CreateInstance to create object of class which is having private constructor?

Tags: c#

By using `Activator.CreateInstance` we can create objects of a class, even if the constructor is private.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: What's in your private constructor that you want to hide from `Activator.CreateInstance`?

Comment: @Erich, potentially yes. Depending on what the OP is trying to achieve, there may be a better way that doesn't involve having a private constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection breaks encapsulation in general. **Any** private member of **any** type (constructor, method, property, field, you name it) can be accessed using reflection (`Activator.CreateInstance` falls under this umbrella).

That said, if you want your type not to be instantiatable via [the overload of `Activator.CreateInstance` generally used to overcome `private` constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he47tyc4.aspx), you could get rid of its parameterless constructor for your type altogether (by defining only constructors that take parameters).

You still can't do anything about someone using one of the overloads that specifies parameters, though.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: You can't

The more detailed answer: Read about [.NET code access security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0.aspx). It's possible to run code in a limited-trust environment; partially trusted code can't bypass access restrictions. By default, code runs with full trust, and full-trust code can use reflection to access private members.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to prevent it from happening, but it's not pretty:
In the private constructor, you can add some checks based on the `StackTrace` class. Create a new `StackTrace` within your private constructor. Call `GetFrames()` and iterate over them, checking to see if any of the frames contain a call from the `Activator` type. Within the `StackFrame`. you can query for the method via `GetMethod` function. That returns a `MethodBase` which inherits from `MemberInfo` class. That will have the `DeclaringType` property you care about.

As you iterate over the stack frame, if you notice that one the invoking types is the `Activator` class, you know your private constructor is being called via that approach.

You should only need to look at two stackframes (skipping over your current one) to verify this.  I believe that there is one other way besides the `Activator` class to instantiate using reflection, but I don't remember it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an older post but I ran into it and I just couldn't resist.

There is a way to prevent `Activator` to access the private constructor. For example in the Singleton pattern class using a nested class:

```
public sealed class SingletonClass
{


 SingletonClass()
    {
    }

public static SingletonClass Instance
{
    get
    {
        return InnerClass.instance;
    }
}

class InnerClass
{
    static InnerClass()
    {
    }

    internal static readonly SingletonClass instance = new SingletonClass();
}
```

}